# react-native - createBottomTabNavigator initial render height problem

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I use bottom-tab-navigator https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator in my app, I took example from official web site here: [Try this example on Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Bottom%20Tabs%20Navigator%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.1.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.0.2%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.2%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.0.6&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fbottom-tab-example.js) but on starting app it has strange height visual effect, which you can see here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxKUlkP0eJ4

I tried to set bottom tab height to 50, it's bit better, but there is still icons jump down effect (it's visible if you set height to 150)

```
<Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
        tabBarStyle:[
          {
            height:50
          }
        ]
      }}
```

How to fix that strange visual effect? Appreciate any help.

Comment: May be caused by some rerender happening at the startup of the app changing the height of the component that contains your navigator

Comment: I tried sipmlest example from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/ at the bottom of the page, and it doesn't work correctly...